# Keep values of dropdownlist (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I keep values of dropdownlist after return from a submit?

I have the following structure.

On controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastro(CadastroViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        var usuario = Mapper.Map<CadastroViewModel, Usuario>(viewModel);
        servicoDeAplicacaoDeUsuario.Inserir(usuario);
    }
    catch (ValidationException validationException)
    {
        this.ModelState.Clear();
        foreach (var error in validationException.Errors)
            this.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);

        return View("Cadastro", viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

So above it will return some validation errors, but the viewModel does not have the filled list (dropdown) to return.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cadastro", "Cadastro", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <ul class="login-signup-list">
        <li>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.NomeCompleto, new { @class = "span10", autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = RecursoDeCadastro.NomeCompleto, maxlength = 100 })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Email, new { @class = "span10", type="email", placeholder = RecursoDeCadastro.Email, maxlength = 100 })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Senha, new { @class = "span10", type="password", placeholder = RecursoDeCadastro.Senha, maxlength = 50 })
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdPais, new SelectList(Model.Paises, "Id", "Nome"), new { @class = "span10" } )
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdUF, new SelectList(Model.UFs, "Id", "Nome"), new { @class = "span10" } )
        </li>
        <li>                    
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdMunicipio, new SelectList(Model.Municipios, "Id", "Nome"), new { @class = "span10" } )
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">@RecursoDeCadastro.CriarConta</button>
        </li>
// ... ?
}
```

I could take every list from database again and set it´s value using the Id (IdUF for example)  that came with viewModel on post, because i'm losing only the list. But I think that it´s not necessary that request to database again.

Is there a workaround for it? 
Can I use session by logged user? How?

Thanks.

Wilton Ruffato Wonrath

Comment: You're working in a stateless technology. What happens when you hit submit is a request.. there is no reason why you can't hit the database again. Generally there are at least one database calls per request.

Comment: You have to set the value from controller itself. Usually, such requirements are not needed because in such cases we are using ajax form posts.

Comment: I thought about the stateless situation like you sad and got the data from database again. The problem now is that my dropdown has value but does not come selected with the previous value, but the value is ok in the model. I searched and found a way using SelectListItem and SelectList. Do you know if there is a way to use my own list with the selected value? Or a way to cast my List<UFs> into SelectList without foreach?

Thanks again.